# Ansible: stdout of commands that end with reboot

Tags: ansible

I have the following problem. I use Ansible to run an installation script on remote servers, and the script reboots the server in the end. As a result, the task ends with "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Connection closed" failure. I use `ignore_unreachable: true` to prevent the task from failing, but my main problem is that I would like to be able to see stdout of the task. For some reason, both stderr and stdout don't seem to be present for tasks that ended with connection closed by the server.

To make things worse, the install script runs as a non-privileged user, but at some point asks for sudo password, and for various reasons I can't use `NOPASSWD` option in sudoers config for this user. To work adound this, I eventually decided to use [`expect`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html) module to run the script:

```yaml
- name: Launch installer script
  expect:
    command: "./install.sh"
    chdir: "{{ installer_directory }}"
    creates: "{{ product_base_directory }}/uninstall.sh"
    responses: "{{ sudo_password_prompt | items2dict}}"
    timeout: 1200 # 20 minutes
  ignore_errors: true
  ignore_unreachable: true
  register: install_script_output

- name: "Display installer script output"
  debug:
    msg:
      stdout: "{{ install_script_output.stdout_lines | default([]) }}"
      stderr: "{{ install_script_output.stderr_lines | default([]) }}"
  failed_when: "{{ not install_script_output.msg.startswith('Failed to connect') }}"
```

If the install script fails, the next task is perfectly able to access `stdout_lines` and `stderr_lines` fields of the registered variable. However, if the script succeeds and the remote server goes offline, the variable contains nothing but two fields: `failed` and `msg`.

```
{
  "failed": true,
  "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: System is going down. Unprivileged users are not permitted to log in anymore. For technical details, see pam_nologin(8).\n\nConnection closed by 10.10.10.10 port 22"
}
```

Is there a way to view `stdout` of such tasks that result in closing the connection with the remote host?

Comment: The prudent way would be to adapt the installation script (or replicate it with Ansible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *... both `stderr` and `stdout` don't seem to be present for tasks that ended with connection closed by the server.*

That's correct and the expected behavior. It is obviously because of the fact that Ansible won't able to transfer the information back from the Remote Node to the Control Node since a reboot was triggered and therefore the Remote Code executed got terminated externally.

> *Is there a way to view `stdout` of such tasks that result in closing the connection with the remote host?*

It depends on how one look at the problem. Out-of-box and without implementing workarounds, no. This is because of the fact that `stdout` was hold in memory only on the Remote Node and not logged.

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible: How to display realtime shell `stdout`](https://serverfault.com/a/972664/448950)
- [Ansible Issue #3887 - Expose realtime output from 'shell'](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/3887)
- [Ansinle Proposal #92 - Provide mechanism for streaming logs from modules](https://github.com/ansible/proposals/issues/92)

**Further Reading**

... in case of the development and debugging scripts or Custom Modules.

- [Ansible: Run Shell command with `async` module to capture its output on runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75295004/6771046)
- [How can I show progress for a long-running Ansible task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194021/how-can-i-show-progress-for-a-long-running-ansible-task/42773566#42773566)

---

**How to proceed further?**

Since it seems that you have access to installer script, the easiest way to deal with the use case seems to be to change the behavior of the installer script itself. During this it might also be possible to implement logging if not already available. From the script perspective logging local into in example `/var/log/script.stdout.log` and `script.stderr.log`, which could be `fetch`ed or `slurp`ed on the Control Node if necessary.

One could also simply move the reboot out of the script and let the script run end before rebooting. By doing this the requested information will be collected. It would only be necessary to implement a single additional Ansible task to reboot the Remote Node afterwards.